# My Laravel boot method is not accepting any conditional

Tags: laravel

I have an app with which a user is able to view various posts.
In my model, I use boot method that will run again any query in that model so that only active posts are shown and all works so far.

```
protected static function boot()
{
   parent::boot();

  static::addGlobalScope('active', function (Builder $builder) {
      $builder->where('active', 1);
  });
}
```

But now it happens that when a user is in the app, it became mandatory that he should be able to block a post, so every-time he logs in the app, he will never see that post again.

I created a hidden posts table that receives `post` and `user_id`.

```
public function hide_post(Request $request, $post_id){

    $user = $this->getAuthorizedUser($request->header('X-User-Auth-Token'));
    $user = User::find(201);
    if (!$user) {
        return response()->json(['error' => true, 'code' => 401, 'message' => INVALID_AUTH_TOKEN], 401);
    }

    $data = [
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'post_id' => $post_id,
        'created_at' => now(),
        'updated_at' => now()
    ];

    $reported_post = DB::table('hidden_posts')->insert($data);

    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'code' => 200, 'message' => 'Posted successfully hidden'], 200);
}
```

So far the table is updated.

Is there a way I can amend my boot method to also ensure that the app does not show me posts that I did hide?

I tried this:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

   $hidden = DB::table('hidden_posts')->whereUser(Auth::id())->pluck('post_id')->toArray();

    // A global scope is applied to all queries on this model
    // -> No need to specify 'active' restraints on every query

    static::addGlobalScope('active', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->whereNotIn('post_id', $hidden);
        $builder->where('active', 1);
    });
}
```

But when I try to view all my posts just for testing purposes, with a new endpoint I created, here comes the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `post_id` from `hidden_posts` where `user` is null)
```

I thought of adding if statement in the boot method, but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Do I understand the business logic correctly? There is bunch of posts and bunch of users. Each user can decide to hide a post so they don't see it anymore. If thats the case I'd have a relationship between users and posts and just use pure eloquent to handle the use-case you want to achieve by querying [`Post::doesntHave()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence).

Comment: @Kyslik a user has many posts and a post belongs to a user yes. But if i am on the site/app, I want to be able to hide any post, even if that post does not belong to me. So, from the moment I click to hide onwards, I will never see that post again on my side only. This is why I created my hidden_posts table, which receives the post id, and the id of the user of clicked on that post.

Comment: It should be `whereUserId` not `whereUser` . In general `whereSomeThing($y)` is shorthand for `where('some_thing','=',$y)`

Comment: @apokryfos thans for that...but now I get an error that says hidden variable undefined

Comment: Alright so you want to `unpublish` kind of functionality; all you need to do is simply flag just like you already have (`active`) I do not understand why do you want another table (`hidden_posts`) to be involved it doesn't make sense. I'd simply implement [soft-deletes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#soft-deleting) and thats it.

Comment: For that your function needs to "use" it like e.g. `function (Builder $builder) use ($hidden) {`

Comment: @Kyslik I understand where you coming from..but the problem is that oter users should be able to see that post. I am hiding the post for me only

Comment: If thats so my first comment holds. Create a relationship between the posts / users and use `doesntHave` linked above. Try using Eloquent as much as possible; when you get stuck use raw queries / query builder.

Comment: @apokryfos I clicked to hide the post and the table hidden_posts get updated.
I added this now: static::addGlobalScope('active', function (Builder $builder) use ($hidden) {
But when view all posts I still get the post with id that I used to hide

Comment: @Kyslik if this wasnt about fixing other people's bad practices I would have definately done the right :).

Comment: You have the opportunity to leave the code in better state than you got it. I know its hard, and takes more time but sometimes its the only way. Good Luck!

Comment: This depends on when you're running the query. Your boot function will run when the framework boots and you're loading all hidden models at that time. If you then hide a model and then get all models that model will still appear as not hidden because it was not hidden when the scope was applied. However it should appear hidden the next time the framework boots. If this is what is happening you can move the `$hidden = ...` line inside the scope callback.

Comment: @apokryfos maybe you can paste a code as answer. Cause right now am understanding that you want me to remove  $hidden = DB::table('hidden_posts')->whereUserId(Auth::id())->pluck('post_id')->toArray(); which will give me undefined hidden variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `boot` function runs when the application is booted and only then. At that point you are collecting all hidden posts and hidding them using a global scope. However when you hide a post after the application has been booted it will not be reflected in the scope until you boot the application again. You can avoid this by having the scope get the hidden models when needed:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();        
    static::addGlobalScope('active', function (Builder $builder) {
        $hidden = DB::table('hidden_posts')
               ->whereUserId(Auth::id())
               ->pluck('post_id')->toArray();
        $builder->whereNotIn('post_id', $hidden);
        $builder->where('active', 1);
    });
}
```

You might be able to save on some querying by doing :

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();        
    static::addGlobalScope('active', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->whereNotIn('post_id', function ($query) {
             $query->from('hidden_posts')
                  ->whereUserId(\Auth::id())
                  ->select('post_id');
        });
        $builder->where('active', 1);
    });
}
```

Comment: The reason why my code is not working it's because am not getting the user id actually. The front-end of the app is with reactive native and I cannot really use the Auth mechanism

Comment: @deSousa I'd consider using Laravel Passport so you can use OAuth 2 for authentication.